# Entropy violated?

Tags: entropy

There is a pin hole separating an evacuated chamber and a chamber filled with air. When the pinhole is opened, the air diffuses out, and nitrogen diffuses fast compared to oxygen. This momentarily separates nitrogen and oxygen. Doesnt it violate 2nd law of thermodynamics?

Comment: How is it violating the law according to you ?

Comment: @Steeven Please tell me you don't think the entropy of a gas decreases when  its volume increases.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Woops, typo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question, and the answer has to be "No". I suggest you count the number microstates to prove it.